# Passing Null Value To Stored Procedure When Input Parameter Type Is Numeric

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, procedure

I'm trying to send some value to Stored Procedure from Java service where that value can be `NULL` or `Numeric`.

Procedure:

```
public xxxxCoxxxxctTexxsDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, xxxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_VALUE);
        setFunction(false);
        LOG.info("CopyContractTermsDAOImpl()");
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("P_CxxxxxxT_TxxxS_ID", Types.VARCHAR));
  ----> declareParameter(new SqlParameter("P_PROGRAM_TERM_STG_ID", Types.NUMERIC)); <----
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("P_SUCCESS_OUT", Types.VARCHAR));
        compile();
    }
```

The line marked with the arrow is where I want to pass a null value but while sending parameters if I send null as a value getting an error.

```
     inParameters.put("P_CxxxxxxT_TxxxS_ID", string);
---> inParameters.put("P_PROGRAM_TERM_STG_ID",null); <---
```

Error:

```
2022-07-25 17:24:20.380  INFO 72716 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.a.r.s.exception.ApplicationException   : CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call MHCPM.xxxx_Coxxxxct_Texxs(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

Comment: how does the function look like?

Comment: I can not show the procedure here but I can tell you the sequence is the same there is no issue with the sequence I've followed the proper order

Comment: In the procedure, there are a total of 3 IN parameters and 2 Out parameters, where in parameters are 2 ID fields of Integer type and 1 with VarChar type from java service when I'm trying to pass one of the Id as null it's showing above error

Comment: IMO this error comes from inside the function not because of the function parameters. I assume that in the function the null value is assigned to a variable